# Selenium WebDriver: Variable for different countries

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hi I'm new to Java and Selenium and I am trying to figure out some things. And please forgive my English.

Let's assume I have 2 or more countries and I only have one "testclass" for logging in.

For Country1 I have the username:*"user1"* and the password *"pass1"*. 
For country2 it is *"user2"* and *"password2"*. I do not want to hardcode the username and the password into the testclass so I created another one which holds the variable e.g
   `public static final String iUsername = "user1";`

and

`public static final String mUsername = "user2";`.

In the testclass I would call it e.g

`driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys(Constant.iUsername);`.

My Question is how can I select before I start the test the other username (mUsername) without always changing the code at the testclass.

Like I said I'm new and I am not so good at explain things.

Thanks

Comment: You should read from an array based on a variable like country that you can set it before suite or you can get from the environment.Another option could be to use/create a data provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pseudo-code that shows a possible design for your test:

1. Create a class for Users:

   ```
   public class User {
       public String username;
       public String password;

       public Users(String username, String password) {
           this.username = username;
           this.password = password;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create a class to store their information (similar to your static class):

   ```
   public class UserFixture {
       public static User userUSA = new User("userUSA", "passUSA");
       public static User userUK = new User("userUK", "passUK");
       public static User userChina = new User("userChina", "passChina");
       public static User userFrance = new User("userFrance", "passFrance");
   }
   ```
3. Create a HashMap with the list of countries you want to test:

   ```
   public class AccessTest {
       List<String> countries = Arrays.asList(
           "www.website.com", 
           "www.website.co.uk", 
           "www.website.ch", 
           "www.website.com.fr");

       Map<Users, List<String>> userCountries = new HashMap<Users, List<String>>();
       userCountries.put(UserFixture.userUSA, countries);
       userCountries.put(UserFixture.userUK, countries);
       userCountries.put(UserFixture.userChina, countries);
       userCountries.put(UserFixture.userFrance, countries);

       public static test() {
           // u = user; c = country 
           userCountries.forEach((u, c) ->
               c.forEach( country ->
                   goToUrl(country);
                   login(u);
                   // Write the rest of the test below
               )
           )
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I don't have to deal with #3 but I use practically an exact copy of #1 and #2 all the time and it works great for me. Good answer!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, but easiest one is -

You can have one properties file containing your user ids and passwords and one extra parameter (say Choice = 1 or 2) defining which user you want to use. This way you will not need to have the class holding constants. Then you can have one class for reading parameter file. Create a login function where you can pass the login data. Then in your test class you can use ids and their passwords based on the value of Choice.

```
if(properties.getProperty("Choice") == 1)
{ Login(properties.getProperty("User1Id"),properties.getProperty("Pass1"));
else if (properties.getProperty("Choice") == 2)
{ Login(properties.getProperty("User2Id"),properties.getProperty("Pass2"));
```

}
    else //some error

This way you just have to change the value of choice variable in your properties file.

Comment: OKay Thanks. 
But let's assume I have like 10 different countries like ebay.com ebay.co.uk ebay.it...
If I would fill my test class with 10 else if it would get pretty full and unclear. 
Is there any solution to like change just the variable at the beginning of the class to like "3" and it takes the id, password... of the properties file?
Thanks

Comment: Not a scalable solution.

Comment: @P.Schultz updated to solve your problem. You can also go for Excel to store data and use apache POI to access it.